# Как собрать DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Я застрял на вот какой задачке. У меня есть DataFrame.

[CSV здесь](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/wAc_kBnnV0sF1g)

Вот как DataFrame примерно выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У [ID] может быть несколько разных значений [Name].

```
pivot_sub=subset.pivot_table(index=['ID','Name'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно, что у id==0 есть name=[250011786293520,250021070679134,250021074171178,250021082683076] и тд.

Мне надо сформировать  DataFrame, чтобы эти значения name попадали в список для своего ID. Что-то вроде этого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получается коряво и долго с использование двух циклов for. А хочется, чтобы оптимальнее это сделать. Прошу помощи в этом вопросе

Comment: Вам нужно сгруппировать в список только столбец Name или все столбцы с одинаковым ID необходимо перевести в список?

Comment: @ strawdog В список только столбец Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы выбрали неверный метод, на мой взгляд. `pivoting` служит для изменения формата таблицы. Вам же нужен метод `groupby`:

```
res = df.groupby("ID")["Name"].apply(list).to_frame()
```

res:

```
                                                               Name
ID                                                                 
0                 [250021070679134, 250021082683076, 25002107417...
124970031869501                  [250011810814438, 250011810814438]
124970063376001                                   [250021068361830]
125370072570922                                   [250621002223828]
130690033033927                                   [250203314431170]
...                                                             ...
8696960459627978                                  [250990284511425]
8698780349365678                 [250203317990585, 250203317990585]
8698900455893100  [640032025196127, 640032025196127, 64003202519...
9114386532897278                                  [250110218200531]
9114631047782000                                  [250021075907243]
```

Либо, если вам нужен не список, а строка значений через запятую (правда, непонятно, зачем), о можно сделать так:

```
res1 = df.groupby("ID")["Name"].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([str(i) for i in x])).to_frame()
```

res1:

```
                                                               Name
ID                                                                 
0                 250021070679134, 250021082683076, 250021074171...
124970031869501                    250011810814438, 250011810814438
124970063376001                                     250021068361830
125370072570922                                     250621002223828
130690033033927                                     250203314431170
...                                                             ...
8696960459627978                                    250990284511425
8698780349365678                   250203317990585, 250203317990585
8698900455893100  640032025196127, 640032025196127, 640032025196127
9114386532897278                                    250110218200531
9114631047782000                                    250021075907243
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо.